# Can not play Audio CD in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, vlc, dvd, audio-cd

I have two Audio CDs to prepare for my upcoming English test. I can play the first CD by execute `vlc cdda://` in konsole (I use Arch Linux with KDE). I also note that the Audio CD appears in the Devices panel in Dolphin. Unfortunately, for the second CD, nothing appears in Dolphin and I also can't play this CD with vlc.

I run `cd-info /dev/cdrom`  with the the second CD inside and get

```
cd-info version 0.93 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Copyright (c) 2003-2005, 2007-2008, 2011-2013 R. Bernstein
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
CD location   : /dev/cdrom
CD driver name: GNU/Linux
   access mode: IOCTL

Vendor                      : Slimtype
Model                       : DVD A  DS8A5SH  
Revision                    : XAA2
Hardware                                  : CD-ROM or DVD
Can eject                                 : Yes
Can close tray                            : Yes
Can disable manual eject                  : Yes
Can select juke-box disc                  : No

Can set drive speed                       : No
Can read multiple sessions (e.g. PhotoCD) : Yes
Can hard reset device                     : Yes

Reading....
  Can read Mode 2 Form 1                  : Yes
  Can read Mode 2 Form 2                  : Yes
  Can read (S)VCD (i.e. Mode 2 Form 1/2)  : Yes
  Can read C2 Errors                      : Yes
  Can read IRSC                           : Yes
  Can read Media Channel Number (or UPC)  : Yes
  Can play audio                          : Yes
  Can read CD-DA                          : Yes
  Can read CD-R                           : Yes
  Can read CD-RW                          : Yes
  Can read DVD-ROM                        : Yes

Writing....
  Can write CD-RW                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-R                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-RAM                       : Yes
  Can write DVD-RW                        : No
  Can write DVD+RW                        : No
__________________________________

Disc mode is listed as: Error in getting information
++ WARN: error in ioctl CDROMREADTOCHDR: No medium found

cd-info: Can't get first track number. I give up.
```

I installed `libdvdread, libdvdcss, libdvdnav` and tried with `vlc dvd:///dev/sr0` but konsole returned errors. Can anyone help me to play the CD?

Comment: Is it possible that the 2nd CD is physically bad or perhaps written at a speed too high?

Comment: You may try with another program. For example `mpv cdda://`

Comment: @schaiba The 2nd CD plays well with Windows Media Player on Windows, so I don't think that CD is damaged.

Comment: As @Francesco Turco suggest, I installed `mpv` and now I can play that CD. But I am still curious why `mpv` can play, but `vlc` can't?

Comment: @macnguyen: I don't know why mpv works and vlc doesn't, but I have a suggestion for you: why don't you try to rip the CD to the hard disk with a tool such as `cdparanoia`? Rip once and then forget about it. Also `libdvdread`, `libdvdcss` and `libdvdnav` are tools for watching/ripping video DVDs, not audio CDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's your error:

```
++ WARN: error in ioctl CDROMREADTOCHDR: No medium found
```

It seems your medium is either [non-redbook compliant](http://homerecording.com/bbs/general-discussions/newbies/redbook-compliant-293712/), is faulty or damaged, or your drive is faulty (seems less likely considering the other CD works).

If your CD works on another audio player, it may be that it contains [Digital Restrictions Management](https://www.defectivebydesign.org/what_is_drm_digital_restrictions_management) technology, which you don't have the required technology to interact with.

Comment: I can open audio files of the 2nd CD on my friend's computer (which is running Windows), but only by Windows Media Player. VLC can't open the files in that CD. I also test with a Linux Mint Live USB, but VLC on the LiveUSB can not play the CD, too. So is it restricted by DRM?

Comment: "Audio files"? If this is a CDDA disk then there shouldn't be "audio files", unless your OS is abstracting them. Are you sure this is CDDA at all?

Comment: I may be misunderstand, but when I put the CD into my laptop, a tab 'Audio CD' appears in Devices panel in Dolphin. So I think it's audio files. Is it right?